# Vec: filter: I'm not sure if there should be a case for the constructor []

Tags: agda

I'm trying to define a filter function for Vec:

```
vecFilter : ∀ {P : Pred A p} → Decidable P → ∀ {n m : ℕ} → Vec A (m + n) → Vec A n
vecFilter P? [] = []
vecFilter P? (x ∷ xs) with does (P? x)
... | false = vecFilter P? xs
... | true  = x ∷ vecFilter P? xs
```

I based this on `Data.List` `filter` and also on `Data.Vec` `count`.

I get the following error message:

```
I'm not sure if there should be a case for the constructor [],
because I get stuck when trying to solve the following unification
problems (inferred index ≟ expected index):
  ℕ.zero ≟ n + m
when checking that the pattern [] has type Vec A (n + m)
```

I wonder if this has to do with the fact that I'm using `Vec A (n + m)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed type of `filter` is very generous:

```
vecFilter : ∀ {P : Pred A p} → Decidable P → ∀ {n m : ℕ} → Vec A (m + n) → Vec A n
```

It claims that for any decidable predicate `P`, and **any pair of natural numbers `n` and`m`**, you can transform a vector of `m + n` elements to a vector of `n` elements.

However, this clearly cannot be true; for example, if I choose `P` as `const ⊤` and `n` as 0 and `m` as 1, your filter function is required to produce an empty vector from a one-element vector, even though the predicate will necessarily hold for that one element.

So what can we do? The choice of how many elements have been removed (`m`) must be made by your function; in other words, it must somehow be existentially quantified. The practical way of doing it is to say that `vecFilter` can work on any vector of any length, and then return a dependent pair of the number of elements removed, and the remaining elements:

```
vecFilter : ∀ {P : Pred A p} → Decidable P → ∀ {n : ℕ} → Vec A n → Σ ℕ λ m → Vec A (n ∸ m)
```

Of course, the real implementation in the standard library is somewhat nicer it uses a unique representation for the difference in length (whereas `n ∸ m` allows things like `10 ∸ 10000` to represent an empty result).

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that `filter` is already implemented for `Vec` [Data.Vec](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Vec.html). I was searching in `Data.Vec.Base`